# Salesforce workflow

Tags: workflow

Im new to Salesforce and am a bit stuck. Why is this Workflow not running:

```
    AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Owner.Price_Level_Type__c, "Sales Rep"), 
    IF(Sales_Rep_Price__c = Sales_Price__c >= 0, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

The logic should be:

> if Opportunity Owner has a Price Level Type picklist value of "Sales Rep" and the "Sales Price" currency value is greater than or equal to the "Sales Rep Price" value update the Status field to Approved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it Active..?

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow will look like this:

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Opportunity.Owner.Price_Level_Type__c, "Sales Rep"), 
    (Sales_Price__c >= Pricebookentry.Sales_Rep_Price__c)
)
```

Updated the answer based on your comment,  since you were referring the formula.

Comment: Hi Santanu, both the Sales Price and Sales Rep Price fields are formula fields so I get a syntax error with the above

Comment: formula fields cannot be used in other formula fields

Comment: can you post how the Sales_Price__c & Sales_Rep_Price__c formula fields are displayed

Comment: Formula Options
Data Type FormulaThis formula references multiple objects    
Decimal Places 2    
PricebookEntry.Sales_Rep_Price__c

Comment: the formula field is: PricebookEntry.Sales_Rep_Price__c

Comment: You can use this formula entry in the above cases, so that will not refer to your previous formula

Comment: Updated the answer based on your comment

Comment: Hi Santanu, I get a syntax error as the PricebookEntry.Sales_Rep_Price__c field is not accessible from the Quote record